# How to use Xelatex with vim-latexsuite?

Tags: compiling, vim-latex

I want to compile my tex file with Xelatex `\ll`

My file started with

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
```

but `xelatex` is not used

I am on

```
$ pacman -Q vim-latexsuite                        
vim-latexsuite 1:1.10.0-3

$ pacman -Q vim           
gvim 8.2.1522-1
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle XeLaTeX with vim-LatexSuite, you have to create rules for calling XeLaTeX.

Modify these lines to fit your system, and add them to your `.vimrc`:

```
"Add XeLaTex rules
let g:Tex_CompileRule_xe = 'xelatex $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_xe = 'xdg-open'

"Set default target to XeLatex
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'xe'
```

How to adapt these rules to your system?
An example: if your current default pdf viewer works fine, use

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_xe = g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf
```

If you do not set the default target to XeLaTeX, you can set the target of your current vim buffer to XeLaTeX with

```
:TTarget xe
```